# Tweak Meta for Post to work it for Pages also

Tags: custom-field, metabox

I'm trying to register the metaboxes for both posts and pages. This code registers meta only for posts.

Can someone guide me how to accomplish this? (keeping the fact in mind that i want "LESS IS MORE" code attitude)

```
function add_custom_meta_box()
{
   add_meta_box("demo-meta-box", "Option Page to select Page Template", "klogeto_template_option_meta", "post", "normal", "high", null);
}
add_action("add_meta_boxes", "add_custom_meta_box");
```

I simply added this:

```
add_meta_box("demo-meta-box", "Option Page to select Page Template", "klogeto_template_option_meta", "page", "normal", "high", null);
```

It has created the option in the back-end, [but it can't save the Options.](https://www.screencast.com/t/eAI2kkQiQS)

[Here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/267822/wordpress-change-post-templates-but-not-drop-down-but-image-selection) is the source to the full code I'm using.

Comment: Hi. do you save the meta boxes? That is some important question.

Comment: [Reference Code](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/267822/wordpress-change-post-templates-but-not-drop-down-but-image-selection). I can also send full file if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a line in the code reference, which is used to save the meta values:

```
$slug = "post";
if($slug != $post->post_type) {
    return $post_id;
}
```

This will simply end the function if you are not on a post. To allow saving data on a page, use this instead (remove the `$slug`):

```
if('post' != $post->post_type || 'page' !=$post->post_type) {
    return $post_id;
}
```

Comment: Ok Let me try sir.

Comment: I have also put this →array('post','page'), but for now it doesnt work.

Comment: @TheWPNovice Do you have any custom post types? If you don't, you can simply remove this piece of code to break the `return` completely.

Comment: No id o not have any custom post type sir.

Comment: You are right boss. Now it works. Thanks for all your help sir.

Comment: @TheWPNovice You're welcome. My memory is a bit rusty, i can't remember how to check if we are on `page.php`. However, removing the above code will solve the issue.