# How to add a column to edit posts area in admin panel?

Tags: posts

I have a WordPress site, which has a list of playlists, which are essentially custom post types.

There is a screenshot below. I want to extend this so it also includes `playlist_id` as an option of input.

Currently you see it just has Image, Portfolio Title, Categories and Date.

Can anyone advise which file/files I should be looking at to include this new header?

I have searched the entire project for Portolio Title but for some reason it cannot be found.

It is important to note the `post_id` and `playlist_id` are the same thing. The `playlist_id` will actually come from spotify, and i want to be able to insert this to correspond with a playlist.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you see in the edit post columns is controlled by `manage_posts_columns` filter.

By `playlist_id` i assume you are looking for the `post_id` (since you mentioned playlists are simply custom post types). You can do so by using this code in your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
if ( !function_exists('add_playlist_id_to_column') && function_exists('add_theme_support') ) {
    // Add our own column
    function add_playlist_id_to_column($cols) {
        $cols['playlist_id'] = __('PlayList ID','text-domain');
        return $cols;
    }
    // Get the post's ID
    function add_playlist_value($column_name, $post_id) {
        // If there is a post_id set, output it. Otherwise, print NONE.
        if ( $post_id ) {
            echo $post_id;
        } else {
            echo __('None','text-domain');
        }
    }
    // Hook to `manage_posts_columns` to run our function
    add_filter( 'manage_posts_columns', 'add_playlist_id_to_column' );
    add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'add_playlist_value', 10, 2 );
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, really appreciate it. I dont actually mean the `post_id` and `playlist_id` are the same thing. The playlist_id will actually come from spotify, and i want to be able to insert this to correspond with a playlist

Comment: @peterflanagan You are welcome. Since i didn't have access to your code, i couldn't post an accurate answer for you. You need to provide us with the methods you are retrieving the `playlist_id` so i can use it in my answer.

Comment: yeah makes sense. So that is the thing. I want to add an input in the new post so an admin can add in a spotify playlist id. Does this make sense?

Comment: @peterflanagan Yes it does. It's called MetaBox. There are plenty of guides on the internet about how to add one. You can add one by following [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/267822/94498) question, and then use my answer to add a column to your admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the Plugin API, specifically the [`manage_$post_type_posts_custom_column`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_$post_type_posts_custom_column) action and [`manage_{$post_type}_posts_columns`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/manage_$post_type_posts_columns) filter.

You will need to know what you're custom post type is called internally. Once you know that replace `{$post_type}` below. To add the column named "New Column" you will add a new column like this:

```
function wpse_add_column_to_playlists($columns) {
    $columns['new_column'] = __('New Column Name', 'text_domain');
    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_{$post_type}_posts_columns', 'wpse_add_column_to_playlists' );
```

Then we populate the new column:

```
function wpse_populate_new_column( $column, $post_id ) {
    switch ( $column ) {

        case 'new_column' :
            //This is the new column, do stuff to populate it...
            echo (string) $post_id;
            break;

    }
}
add_action( 'manage_{$post_type}_posts_custom_column' , 'wpse_populate_new_column', 10, 2 );
```